# Why isn't the variable value being injected into the template string?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I'm executing this code:

```
var myVariable = "test";
console.log('myVariable=${myVariable}');
```

and getting this print result:

> myVariable=${myVariable}

but was expecting:

> myVariable=test

using fresh installs of code and typescript.

similarly,

```
var arrayOfNumbers: number[] = [1,2,3];
arrayOfNumbers = [3,4,5,6,7,8];
console.log('arrayOfNumbers: ${arrayOfNumbers}');
```

results in a print of

> arrayOfNumbers: ${arrayOfNumbers}

I genuinely find this quite puzzling and wonder if there is some switch I have to throw in vs code to get it to work.

Of course this, in the JavaScript rather than the TypeScript style, works as expected.

`console.log("arrayOfNumbers: " + arrayOfNumbers.toString())`

and prints

> arrayOfNumbers: 3,4,5,6,7,8

Comment: Why wouldn't this work? `console.log(myVariable);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use back ticks, not single quotes

```
var myVariable = "test";
console.log(`myVariable=${myVariable}`);
```

http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=%20%20%20%20var%20myVariable%20%3D%20%22test%22%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20alert(%60myVariable%3D%24%7BmyVariable%7D%60)%3B

Comment: Interesting. In MASTERING TYPESCRIPT, second edition, he specifies apostrophe. I'll drop Nathan a note.

Worked beautifully. Thank you. And thanks to the team for the very helpful formatting suggestion.